# Swift enum function with string parameter calling with a parameter of the enum class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parameters, enums

I'm trying to convert from a string to an enum key value, but I couldn't find any simple method so I hardcoded it, but it still won't work.

I tried using an enum function to return an enum key value from a string, but I can't call it with the string even though I declared it with a String as a parameter.

I then tried to move it to a different class, but the same thing happened.

My relevant code is below.

```
enum pickedColor: String {
case green = "71D25E"
case red = "FF0000"
case maroon = "800000"
case yellow = "FFFF00"
case olive = "808000"
case lime = "00FF00"
case aqua = "00FFFF"
case teal = "008080"
case blue = "0000FF"
case navy = "000080"
case fuchsia = "FF00FF"
case purple = "800080"

func toEnum(_ colorName: String) -> pickedColor {
    if colorName.elementsEqual("green") {
        return .green
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("red") {
        return .red
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("maroon") {
        return .maroon
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("yellow") {
        return .yellow
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("olive") {
        return .olive
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("lime") {
        return .lime
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("aqua") {
        return .aqua
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("teal") {
        return .teal
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("blue") {
        return .blue
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("navy") {
        return .navy
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("fuchsia") {
        return .fuchsia
    }  else {
        return .purple
    }
}

{
```

The code that shows up when I try to call it is this.[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ3PF.png)

When manually completed, it still shows an error of cannot convert string to pickedColor.

I then moved the code to a new class, however, it still does not work.

```
class Color {

func toEnum(_ colorName: String) -> pickedColor {
    if colorName.elementsEqual("green") {
        return .green
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("red") {
        return .red
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("maroon") {
        return .maroon
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("yellow") {
        return .yellow
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("olive") {
        return .olive
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("lime") {
        return .lime
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("aqua") {
        return .aqua
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("teal") {
        return .teal
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("blue") {
        return .blue
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("navy") {
        return .navy
    } else if colorName.elementsEqual("fuchsia") {
        return .fuchsia
    } else {
        return .purple
    }
}
}
```

The second picture of the wrong parameter is here. [Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slDke.png)

What is going on?

Comment: And you should use a `switch` instead of an `if`/`else-if`/`else` ladder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have played around with many variants of doing this over the last couple of years and have settled on the below.  It is similar to @rmaddy's version but the rawValue of the enum is a String so that it is easy to convert back and forth between the name and the enum.

I then have static var's for the actual colours themselves.
This allows me to refer to the colours in a similar way to UIColor

```
view.backgroundColor = Palette.blueColor
```

or

```
view.backgroundColor = Palette.colorNamed("blue")
```

.

```
enum Palette : String
{
    case white
    case orange
    case red
    case pink
    case purple
    case blue

    static func color( named:String) -> UIColor?
    {
        switch named
        {
           case white.rawValue : return whiteColor
           case orange.rawValue : return orangeColor
           case red.rawValue : return redColor
           case pink.rawValue : return pinkColor
           case purple.rawValue : return purpleColor
           case blue.rawValue : return blueColor
           default : return nil
        }
    }

    static let whiteColor = color( withHex:0xffffff)
    static let orangeColor = color( withHex:0xfc622f)
    static let redColor = color( withHex:0xdd202b)
    static let pinkColor = color( withHex:0xff2f7e)
    static let purpleColor = color( withHex:0x9166e6)
    static let blueColor = color( withHex:0x049edd)
}

extension UIColor
{
    convenience init( withHexAlpha hex:UInt32)
    {
        let red   = CGFloat((hex >> 24) & 0xff) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255.0
        let blue  = CGFloat((hex >>  8) & 0xff) / 255.0
        let alpha = CGFloat((hex >>  0) & 0xff) / 255.0

        self.init( red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
    }

    convenience init( withHex hex:UInt32)
    {
       self.init( withHexAlpha:(hex << 8) | 0xff)
    }
}
```

Both with mine and @rmaddy's you don't need to do the `if let` as most UIColor properties will also take a nil

Answer (score 4):

You need to make your `toEnum` function a static function since you are not calling it on a specific enum instance.

You should also name your enum starting with an uppercase letter.

And a `switch` is better than your long `if/else`. I would also consider dealing with an unknown color as well.

```
enum PickedColor: String {
    case green = "71D25E"
    case red = "FF0000"
    case maroon = "800000"
    case yellow = "FFFF00"
    case olive = "808000"
    case lime = "00FF00"
    case aqua = "00FFFF"
    case teal = "008080"
    case blue = "0000FF"
    case navy = "000080"
    case fuchsia = "FF00FF"
    case purple = "800080"

    static func toEnum(_ colorName: String) -> PickedColor? {
        switch colorName {
        case "green":
            return .green
        case "red":
            return .red
        case "maroon":
            return .maroon
        case "yellow":
            return .yellow
        case "olive":
            return .olive
        case "lime":
            return .lime
        case "aqua":
            return .aqua
        case "teal":
            return .teal
        case "blue":
            return .blue
        case "navy":
            return .navy
        case "fuchsia":
            return .fuchsia
        case "purple":
            return .purple
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call it as you tried:

```
if let color = PickedColor.toEnum(colorName) {
    // use color as needed
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus No real good reason other than making a minimal change to the OP's code to explain why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to add a computed property and a switch to convert your enumeration cases to hexa and use the default enumeration rawValue initializer:

```
enum PickedColor: String {
    case green, red, maroon, yellow, olive, lime, aqua, teal, blue, navy, fuchsia, purple
}
```

---

```
extension PickedColor {
    var hexa: String {
        let hexa: String
        switch self {
        case .green:
            hexa = "71D25E"
        case .red:
            hexa = "FF0000"
        case .maroon:
            hexa = "800000"
        case .yellow:
            hexa = "FFFF00"
        case .olive:
            hexa = "808000"
        case .lime:
            hexa = "00FF00"
        case .aqua:
            hexa = "00FFFF"
        case .teal:
            hexa = "008080"
        case .blue:
            hexa = "0000FF"
        case .navy:
            hexa = "000080"
        case .fuchsia:
            hexa = "FF00FF"
        case .purple:
            hexa = "800080"
        }
        return hexa
    }
}
```

---

```
if let color = PickedColor(rawValue: "purple") {
    print(color) // "purple\n"
    print(color.hexa) // "800080"
}
```